# Change keyboard apperance when using Facebook SDK 3.5 for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa, facebook-ios-sdk

I am having a hard time changing the keyboard apperance when the Facebook Login dialog pops up.

The point is that i want the keyboard to be UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert.

I tried with

```
UITextField *test = [UITextField appearance];
[test setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
```

but nothing happens.
I want to change also the style of "Previous" and "Next" buttons.

Thanks in advance.

[image: view from simulator]

Comment: I think **You can't change.Because it is defined by facebook sdk.So please don't waste your time.**

Answer (score 0):

That is not facebook keyboard it is something inbuilt it will appear not only in facebook but in every site where you need to type something. How to change things which are in OS??? but yes you can change keyboard in your app.The iPad Human Interface Guidelines that iPhone OS 3.2 supports keyboard customization http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadHIG/UIElements/UIElements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009446-CH6-SW7

Comment: I know that is inbuild, but i can't change it.

Comment: cus thats not possible. why is that need arised to change it will you tell me that so we can look for some alternatives